# Not able to get random post

Tags: get-posts

I want to display a single random post out of the 5 latest posts in the category 'news'.
The approach I'm using is this:

```
  // Custom function to retrieve catgory ID by category name.
  $cat = $lib->getCatIDbyCatName('news');
  // Retrieve the 5 latest posts
  $news = get_posts( array( 'numberposts' => 5,'category_name' => $cat ) );

  foreach($news as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
    echo the_title(); 
    echo the_intro(); // <- Custom function to retrieve custom field
  endforeach;
```

The above code works and I'm dispalying the title and the custom value of all 5 posts. Now I only want one random post out of these 5 posts. So I do this:

```
  // Get a single random post from fetched posts
  $single_news = $news[rand(0, 4)];

  foreach($single_news as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
    echo the_title(); 
    echo the_intro(); // <- Custom function to retrieve custom field
  endforeach;
```

This however, is not working.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I can do? OR maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Get a single random post from fetched posts   
  $post = $news[rand(0, 4)];    
  setup_postdata($post);     
   echo the_title();      
   echo the_intro(); // <- Custom function to retrieve custom field
```